# Does the path category of a quiver determine the quiver up to isomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory

Let $G$ and $G'$ be [quivers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver). If their [path categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+category#free_category_on_a_directed_graph) $Path[G]$ and $Path[G']$ are isomorphic, does is follow that $G$ is isomorphic to $G'$?

Comment: Vertices are isomorphism classes of objects. How would you characterize edges among all morphisms?

Comment: This is true even if you just ask for Morita equivalence of their path algebras over $\mathbb C$ which is of course implied by isomorphism of path category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Given a Quiver $G$, you can identify $G$ as the subquiver of $Path[G]$ of arrows that are not identity and cannot be written as composite of non-identity arrows. So any isomorphism between $Path[G]$ and $Path[G']$ send elements of $G$ to elements of $G'$ and restrict to an isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$.