# Are free functors usually injective up to isomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, universal-algebra

Let $U$ be the forgetful functor from categories to quivers. Then the left adjoint $F$ of $U$ is the functor sending a quiver to its [path category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+category#free_category_on_a_directed_graph). [It's a fact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410831/does-the-path-category-of-a-quiver-determine-the-quiver-up-to-isomorphism) that $F$ is injective up to isomorphism, i.e., if $Path[G]\cong Path[G']$, then $G\cong G'$.

**Question:** Is it usually the case that "free" functors are injective up to isomorphism? In particular, what can be said about the following setting in universal algebra: for each variety $V$ there is a forgetful functor $U\colon V\to \mathbf{Set}$, which has a left adjoint. Are there examples in which "free" functors are not injective up to isomorphism?

Comment: The abelianization functor from Grp to Ab is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, but is not injective on objects up to isomorphism.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the terminal category a variety of algebras, for the theory with one nullary operation $p$ and one equation $\forall x (p=x)$?  Its free functor is certainly not injective up to isomorphism.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126747/ibn-for-algebraic-theories

Comment: For Jonsson-Tarski algebras the free objects on any two finite sets are isomorphic

Comment: If a variety of universal algebras has a non trivial finite object then you do get injectvity. I don't know if this counts as usually

Comment: If the operations of the variety are finitary and the variety does not satisfy $x\approx y$, then it is the case that $F_V(X)\cong F_V(Y)$ implies $X\cong Y$ whenever $X$ is infinite. This is  Theorem 1 of ``Note on the Isomorphism Problem for Free Algebraic Systems'' by Tsuyoshi Fujiwara, 1955.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!

Comment: I asked the same question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325594/does-a-free-algebra-over-a-nontrivial-monad-have-a-well-defined-dimension  - Eric Wofsey answered with the universal counterexample

Comment: @JeremyRickard In your link, what is a homomorphism $\tau \to \sigma$ of finitary algebraic theories? (It is remarked that "if $τ→σ$ is a homomorphism and $σ$ satisfies IBN, then also $τ$ satisfies IBN".)

Comment: @user1005113 I'm no expert, and won't embarrass myself by trying to give a formal definition, but my informal (and possibly wrong) understanding is that it refers to a way of making a model of $\tau$ from a model of $\sigma$ by defining the $\tau$-operations in terms of the $\sigma$-operations. For example, there is a homomorphism from the theory of Lie algebras to the theory of associative algebras since we can regard an associative algebra as a Lie algebra by defining $[x,y]:=xy-yx$.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are examples where $V$ is a variety of algebras and the left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U: V \to \mathbf{Set}$ is not injective on isomorphism classes of objects. Here are two.

- Take the algebraic theory consisting of no operations and the single equation $x = y$. Then $V$ is the category of sets with at most one element, and $U$ is the inclusion. The left adjoint $F$ maps the empty set to the empty set and every nonempty set to $1$.
- Take the algebraic theory consisting of a single constant $c$ and the equation $x = c$. Then $V$ is the terminal category, and $U$ maps its object to the one-element set $1$. The left adjoint $F$ maps everything to $1$.

Answer (score 7):

If $R$ is any (necessarily noncommutative if it is nonzero) ring that does not have the [Invariant Basis Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) property, then free $R$-modules on different numbers of generators can be isomorphic.